# 'com.example.root.call_permission.CallPermission' is not an enclosing class

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't know what is this error that I'm getting also I didn't quite understand other answers for this here as I'm still learning Android.
[image]

In the above image I'm trying to access 'callPermission' module. I added separate projects as modules to a main project named as 'MasterApp'. Ideally I should be able to access these modules via Intent calls but there's some error here. Same is the scenario with other projects. Any kind of help would be appreciated. If you still want more information so as to what I'm doing I'll attach some screenshots here:
[image]

Main module is 'app' and other modules which have been imported are 'callPermission, 'gpsPermission', 'accountsPermission', 'smsPermission', 'installedAppList','batteryInformation' and 'contactsPermission'

Comment: Instead of `CallPersmission.this` use `MainActivity.this`.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ExampleExplicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the wrong class for creating Intent with the constructor. Here the constructor you need to use:

> Intent(Context packageContext, Class cls)

Read at [Intent(Context packageContext, Class cls)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E))

So you need to pass a Context; **Activity** or **Application** context, etc.

The above Intent constructor takes two parameters:

- A [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) as its first parameter
- The [Class](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html) of the app component to
  which the system should deliver the Intent (in this case, the
  activity that should be started).

Read at [Start Another Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) for related Intent usage.